# Get All WebApplication in a given server in sharepoint using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I am trying to get list of **WebApplication** in a Given Server.

***Get-SpWebapplication*** retrieves all the WebApplication in the Current machine.

I need to get the list of WebApplication in a particual server.
How to Do it.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 5):

To get a list of all SharePoint Web Apps, use the following:

```
Get-SPWebApplication | Select DisplayName, Url
```

Comment: If that's not working for you, add the PowerShell snapin by entering: `Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"`

Answer (score 1):

Go to **"C:\windows\system32\inetsrv"** folder
and try this:
**.\appcmd list wp**